# c# - Using input parameter of lambda expression in if statement

Tags: c#, lambda

I have if statement like this:

```
if (myList.Any(x => s.Contains(x))
{
//some code here
}
```

in which I check if there is a string in myList which is contained in a string s.
Is it somehow possible to get the element x of this list and use it in the if statement showed above (in "//some code here" part), when the condition is met?

Thank you.

Comment: will `myList` contain `null` ever?

Comment: no, it wiil not contain null

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Switch from `Any` to `FirstOrDefault`, that will return the item that matched the test or null if no item was matched.

```
var found = myList.FirstOrDefault(x => s.Contains(x));
if (found != null)
{
//some code here
}
```

If `null` could be considered a "valid value" for a element in `myList` you can create a extension method `TryFirst`

```
public static class ExtensionMethods
{
    public static bool TryFirst<T>(this IEnumerable<T> @this, Func<T, bool> predicate, out T result)
    {
        foreach (var item in @this)
        {
            if (predicate(item))
            {
                result = item;
                return true;
            }
        }
        result = default(T);
        return false;
    }
}
```

This would let you do

```
string foundString;
var wasFound = myList.TryFirst(x => s.Contains(x), out foundString);
if (wasFound)
{
//some code here
}
```

and tell the difference between a `null` in your list and a default result.

The above two methods only act on the first item on the list that the `Contains` will match, if you want to act on all the items use a `Where(` clause and a `foreach`

```
foreach(var item in myList.Where(x => s.Contains(x))
{
//some code here
}
```

---

***You must promise you will not use the following code and use one of the other options first***

You can also do your stated question, it is possible to get a variable assigned to inside lambada. However this can not be done with expression lambadas, only with statement lambadas.

```
string matachedString = null;
if (myList.Any(x => { var found = s.Contains(x);
                      if(found)
                          matachedString = x;
                      return found;
                     });
{
//some code here
}
```

But only do this option as a last resort, use one of the more appropriate methods like `FirstOrDefaut` or write a custom method like `TryFirst` first.

Comment: I am not sure why, but when I use FirstOrDefault you've suggested, it only works when s is equal to x. For example, if s="email", and x="email", it works, but it doesn't work when s="emailaaa" and x="email".

Comment: I would double check that `s` and `x` are what you expect them to be inside the debugger. if you switch to `myList.Any(x => { var found = s.Contains(x); return found;  });` you can put a breakpoint on the return and see the value for `s`, `x` and `found`.

Comment: I found what was the problem. Your solution is OK... There was something in my code causing this behavior (it's not related to the topic, so I will not explain what was the problem).

Answer (score 1):

I'd use `foreach`/`Where()`for this, even if I'm only expecting 0 or 1 result:

```
foreach (var item in myList.Where(x => s.Contains(x)))
{
    //some code here
}
```